# Dont understand why .remove() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am learning jQuery and I do not understand why this fucntion does not work. When I click the button it should remove the div but it does not.

The remove function

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
    $(".editButton").remove();
});
```

Function that creates the div

```
var formatPost = function (d) {
    var s = '';
    s = '<div class="post" data-id="' + d.id + '"><h2 class="postHeading">' + d.title + '</h2>';
    s += d.body;
    s += '<p> Posted on: ' + d.date + '</p>';
    s += '<div class="btn editButton">Edit Post</div>'
    s += '</div>'
    return s;
};
```

Comment: where is the code that attaches the button to the DOM?

Comment: tried `alert()` or `console.log();` to see if the `click` is actually working?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are using direct binding, this works when the element exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Use*,

If you want to remove only button

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

If you want to remove complete post, First, You need to execute the action in current element context so use `this`.
Then use `closest()` to find `post` parent and then use `.remove()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {
    $(this).closest('.post').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: It works even without the closest() but thank you for the detailed explenation. Much better then to just copy code.

Comment: @PavelKašelják, `$(this).remove();` will only remove the `editButton` div, not complete post

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted...as I said I am experimenting with jQuery and learning it right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Event Delegation**.

You added the edit button dynamically. DOM didn't know when was the element is added so we need to traverse from the document or the body or Immediate parent selector to find the element

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes this has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dynamically creating div, use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: @Pavel Kašelják - If you happy with my answer means please accept my answer